# Arduino c+ >> operation

Tags: c++, audio, arduino, bit-shift, dac

I am adapting the example for the Arduino AutoAnalogAudio library entitled 
SDAudioWavPlayer 
which can be found in Examples->AutoAnalogAudio->SDAudio->SDAudioWavPlayer 
This example uses interrupts to repeatedly call the function
void loadBuffer(). The code for that is below

```
/* Function called from DAC interrupt after dacHandler(). Loads data into the dacBuffer */

void loadBuffer() {

  if (myFile) {
    if (myFile.available()) {
      if (aaAudio.dacBitsPerSample == 8) {
        //Load 32 samples into the 8-bit dacBuffer
        myFile.read((byte*)aaAudio.dacBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
      }else{
        //Load 32 samples (64 bytes) into the 16-bit dacBuffer
        myFile.read((byte*)aaAudio.dacBuffer16, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 2);
        //Convert the 16-bit samples to 12-bit
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
          aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] = (aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] + 0x8000) >> 4;
        }
      }
    }else{
      #if defined (AUDIO_DEBUG)
        Serial.println("File close");
      #endif
      myFile.close();
      aaAudio.disableDAC();
    }
  }
}
```

The specific part I am concerned with is the second part of the if statement

```
{
        //Load 32 samples (64 bytes) into the 16-bit dacBuffer
        myFile.read((byte*)aaAudio.dacBuffer16, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 2);
        //Convert the 16-bit samples to 12-bit
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
          aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] = (aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] + 0x8000) >> 4;
        }
      }
```

Despite the comment MAX_BUFFER_SIZE is 256 so 512 bytes are read into 
aaAudio.dacBuffer16. That data was originally 16 bit signed integers (+/- 32k) and dacBuffer16 is an array of 16bit unsigned integers (0-64K). The negative sign is removed by going through the array and adding 2^15 (0x8000) to each element. This makes the negative numbers overflow leaving the positive part of the negative number. Positive numbers  are just increased by 2^15. thus the values are rescalled to lie in 0 -64K. The result is then shifted 4 places right so that only the highest 12 bits remain which is what the Arduino DAC can handle. This all happens in the line

```
aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] = (aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] + 0x8000) >> 4;
```

So far so good.

Now I want to be able to programmatically reduce the volume. As far as I can find the library does not provide a function to do that so I thought that the simplest
thing to do was to change the '4' to 'N' and increase the amount of shifting to 5,6,7.. etc
eg

```
aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] = (aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] + 0x8000) >> N;
```

where N is an integer. I tried this but I got a terribly distorted result which I did not understand.

While fiddling around trying different things I tried the following which works

```
uint16_t sample;
int N = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) 
        {

          sample = (aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] + 0x8000);
          sample = sample >> N;
          // sample = sample / 40;
          aaAudio.dacBuffer16[i] = sample;
          }
```

You can also see that I have commented out simply dividing by a number which works if I want finer control.

My problem is I do not see what the difference is between the two bits of code.
Can anybody enlighten me ?

Comment: I would not rely on overflow procedure, and better do all operations inside a "normal" range.

Comment: This is not my code it is the library example. This procedure is common